# I want to make this happen in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
driverphone| drivername|guarantor1_phone|guarantor2_phone
---------------------------------------------------------
0801       |Mr A       |0803            |0802
0802       |Mr B       |0804            |0801
0803       |Mr C       |0805            |0801
0804       |Mr D       |0802            |0805
0805       |Mr E       |0801            |0803
```

I want to get this result set in SQL Server

```
driverphone| drivername|Total Guaranteed
----------------------------------------
0801       |Mr A       |   3
0802       |Mr B       |   2            
0803       |Mr C       |   2
0804       |Mr D       |   1
0805       |Mr E       |   2
```

That is to select the total number guaranteed by each driver.
driver->guarantor relationship is based on phone numbers.

Comment: Looks like a bad table design. Are the `1` and `2` designations important? If so, they ought to be modelled as *data*, not stored as *metadata* (i.e. inside the column name). The guarantors should be stored as *rows* in a separate table (optionally with the `1`/`2` data in a separate column) and then this query is trivial (and your data is modelled better)

Comment: "I want to make this happen in SQL Server" is not a very informing title. Please edit it and also tell us what you've tried and how your thought process is on processing the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do make LEFT JOIN with both guarantor columns and make a Distinct count of it.

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB (
    driverphone VARCHAR(10)
    ,drivername VARCHAR(10)
    ,guarantor1_phone VARCHAR(10)
    ,guarantor2_phone VARCHAR(10)
    )


INSERT INTO #TAB

SELECT '0801',' Mr A', '0803', '0802'
UNION ALL
SELECT '0802',' Mr B', '0804', '0801'
UNION ALL
SELECT '0803',' Mr C', '0805', '0801'
UNION ALL
SELECT '0804',' Mr D', '0802', '0805'
UNION ALL
SELECT '0805',' Mr E', '0801', '0803'
```

Now do select like below

```
SELECT T.driverphone
    ,T.drivername
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT T2.driverphone) + COUNT(DISTINCT T3.driverphone)
FROM #TAB T
LEFT JOIN #TAB T2 ON T.driverphone = T2.guarantor1_phone
LEFT JOIN #TAB T3 ON T.driverphone = T3.guarantor2_phone
GROUP BY T.driverphone
    ,T.drivername
```

Result will be

```
+-------------+------------+------------------+
| driverphone | drivername | (No column name) |
+-------------+------------+------------------+
|        0801 |  Mr A      |                3 |
|        0802 |  Mr B      |                2 |
|        0803 |  Mr C      |                2 |
|        0804 |  Mr D      |                1 |
|        0805 |  Mr E      |                2 |
+-------------+------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you @Shakeer Mizra, you did a perfect work. Bless you

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest method is `outer apply`:

```
select t.driverphone, t.drivername, g.totalguaranteed
from t outer apply
     (select count(*) as totalguaranteed
      from (values (guarantor1_phone), (guarantor2_phone)) v(guarantor)
      where v.guarantor = t.driverphone
     ) g;
```

Comment: Please, the figure i gave is an abstraction of the physical table. The table name is not reflected in your query. Please can you please use a table name? In my case my table is a join ( guarantors inner join tbldrivers on tbldrivers.driverphone= guarantors.driverphone)

Comment: @FALETINO . . . `t` is the table name.  You can use a CTE with your current query.  But I would really suggest that you ask another question and add your actual query.  Don't change this question, because it already has answers, and such changes are likely to invalidate answers and draw downvotes.  There may be simpler change to your existing query.